# Timer has to remain deleted

Tags: java, android, textview, countdowntimer

```
 CountDownTimer (2000, 0000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        txt1.setText("...");
        txt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txt2.setText("...");
        txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        cancel(); //<----it deletes the Countdown Timer after finished

        }

}.start();
```

I put `cancel()` in `onFinish()`. So when the countdown ends, it deletes itself.
But when I close and restart the application the activity starts from the beginning, and the timer as well.
How can I make it work once?

Comment: `when I close and restart the application the activity starts from the beginning` then what you want?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K  `How can I make it work once?` <------read that all

Comment: Do as in answer @tiny sunlight is saying

Answer (score 1):

No you cant do like this.When you restart `application`,u creat a new `timer`.If you want to achieve it,Try to Store the status in `SharedPrefense`.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("save",MODE_PRIVATE);

if(!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("opened",false)){
    //what you want do once
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("opened", true);
  editor.apply();
}
```